# ctrl-c not working inside lxc container

Tags: linux, signals, lxc

I'm currently working with a build environment that is running inside of a lxc container.

While everything was working fine on my former host system using lxc 1.0.10, linux signals like the SIGINT for ctrl-c are not forwarded any more to the application running inside the container on my new system using lxc 2.0.8.

Can anyone help with getting the SIGINT to work inside the container environment?